# SimpleMembership Entity Framework Code First in MVC 4 Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, entity

I have problem with SimpleMembership I added Internet Application MVC project to my soulution when i had my Domain Project. Everything worked fine, but when I want table UserProfile in my database i get message

> "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot drop database "ShopDBS" because it is
>   currently in use."

Connection string looks like this:

```
    <add name="ShopDBS" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ShopDBS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\ShopDBS.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Next my dbcontext:

```
public class Context:DbContext
{
    public Context():base("ShopDBS")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderItem>  OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AuthorMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BookMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderItemMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerMap());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

My initializer class:

```
public class Initializer:DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context>
{
    protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        var categories = new List<Category>
        {
            new Category { CategoryName="Informatyka"},
            new Category { CategoryName = "Programowanie"},
            new Category { CategoryName="Webmastering"},
            new Category { CategoryName="Inne"}
        };
        foreach(var tmp in categories)
        {
            context.Categories.Add(tmp); 
        }
        context.SaveChanges();

        //Book.
        var book1 = new Book { BookTitle = "C#", BookPicture="~/Photos/1.jpg",
            BookDescription = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum", BookPrice = 15, CategoryID = 1 };
        var book2 = new Book { BookTitle = "Javacript", BookPicture="~/Photos/2.jpg",
            BookDescription = "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt", BookPrice = 35, CategoryID = 1 };
        var book3 = new Book { BookTitle = "Sieci dla początkujacych", BookPicture="~/Photos/3.jpg",
            BookDescription = "system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstance", BookPrice = 18, CategoryID = 2 };
        var book4 = new Book { BookTitle = "Bazy danych od podstaw", BookPicture="~/Photos/4.jpg",
            BookDescription = "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire", BookPrice = 34, CategoryID = 3 };

        //Author
        var author1 = new Author { AuthorFirstName = "John", AuthorLasttName = "Newman", Books = new List<Book>() {book1,book2 } };
        var author2 = new Author { AuthorFirstName = "Paulo", AuthorLasttName = "Coelho", Books = new List<Book>() {book3,book4 } };
        var author3 = new Author { AuthorFirstName = "Adam", AuthorLasttName = "Freeman", Books = new List<Book>() {book2,book4 } };
        var author4 = new Author { AuthorFirstName = "Stephen", AuthorLasttName = "Meyer", Books = new List<Book>(){book3,book2} };


        var authors = new List<Author>();
        authors.Add(author1);
        authors.Add(author2);
        authors.Add(author3);
        authors.Add(author4);
        authors.ForEach(a => context.Authors.Add(a)); 

        context.SaveChanges();

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

}

AppStart

```
        protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new Initializer());
        WebSecConfig.RegisterWebSec();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

And webseconfig class;

```
    public static class WebSecConfig
{
    public static void RegisterWebSec()
    {
        if (!WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Initialized)
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ShopDBS", "UserProfile",
                "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
    }
}
```

In my database i cannot see any other tables only from SimpleMembership like User Profile and othe starts with Membership. Next i get error database is currently use cannot drop. Really thanks for any help.

Comment: just one request  or suggestion why not use Identity 2.0 instead of this creepy old webmatrix

Comment: Ehh because i only know old WebMatrix and in Visual web Developer 2013 this is built in Internet Application template :(